# SQL ODBC - Concurrent transaction with INSERT-SELECT of foreign key information

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, transactions, odbc

I'm implementing an ODBC application where multiple clients are storing data in two tables which have a foreign key relation ship. This application should support different databases in a similar way. Therefor the sql commands are externalized in files and should be written in a similar structure.

To narrow this down I have a simplified example based on SQL Server syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(max) NO NULL
);

CREATE TABLE B
(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    data varchar(max) NO NULL,
    A_id int NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (A_id) REFERENCES A (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

The values are inserted by the following SQL code via `SQLExecDirect`:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO A (name)
VALUES ('John');

INSERT INTO B (data)
VALUES ('Some data', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM A));

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

I've set the following statement attributes:

```
SQLSetStmtAttr(hStmt, SQL_ATTR_CONCURRENCY, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_CONCUR_LOCK, 0));

SQLSetStmtAttr(hStmt, SQL_ATTR_CURSOR_TYPE, (SQLPOINTER) SQL_CURSOR_KEYSET_DRIVEN, 0));

SQLSetStmtAttr(hStmt, SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT, (SQLPOINTER)300, SQL_IS_UINTEGER));
```

The connection attribute for the auto commit is disabled:

```
SQLSetConnectOption(m_hDBC, SQL_AUTOCOMMIT, SQL_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF);
```

When testing in parallel from two clients I'm running into the situation that the max primary key from A is not the one from the current transaction, but from the one of the other client.

In other words the INSERT command to table A from client 1 is visible to the INSERT-SELECT clause of the client 2. How is is possible to avoid this?

BTW I'm aware that I could use OUTPUT to retrieve the primary key in the first INSERT statement for SQL Serer. Some other SQL dialects have RETURNING, but there are also dialect which don't offer the possibility to return this ID, therefor I like to stay away from this technique and like to use an INSERT with a nested SELECT of the max id of table A.

I wonder what I'm missing to make this transaction save.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using SCOPE_IDENTITY inside your transaction to isolate scope to the clients context? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I did not test it with SCOPE IDENTITY, but this is the similar situation as using OUTPUT or RETURNING. I'm searching for a mechanism which could be used for all database systems in a similar manner.